# Put all rows in a table into an array of arrays in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a table like so for Outbound usage of Pharmacies

```
Pharmacy Name | Pharmacy ID | Call | SMS | Email | P | Total
------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1        | 123456      |  1   | 2   |  3    | 4 |  10
------------------------------------------------------------
Test 2        | 123457      |  1   | 2   |  3    | 4 |  10
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to export this table to an excel sheet. How would I go about this when clicking a button and passing this data to my controller?

So far I have

```
$("tr").each(function () {

     alert( $("td").text());
});
```

But it is giving me all the tds.

I would like to be able to store the values of each row into an object.

Comment: there are several plugins to convert html table to csv, use your favorite search engine to find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
$('tr').map(function(i, tr) {
  return $(tr).find('td').map(function(j, td) {
    return $(td).text();
  });
});
```

EDIT:
how weird. Jquery seems to flatten them.

```
var parentArr = [];
$('tr').each(function() {
  var children = [];
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    children.push($(this).text());
  });
  parentArr.push(children);
});
```

this could definitely be solved a little more elegantly using ecmascript 5 or underscore/lodash methods.

Comment: Thanks that is what I am looking for, now I am trying to create an array of arrays. Basically with my output above it would have an array with 2 objects. I posted what I have below

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far

```
    var items;
    var data = [];

    $('tr').map(function (i, tr) {
        items = [];
        return $(tr).find('td').map(function (j, td) {

            items[j] = $(td).text();
            data[i].push(items[j]);
            return $(td).text();
        });

        alert(data);
    });
```